# Passing a smarty foreach cycle variable into php code

Tags: php, smarty

I have foreach loop in smarty:

```
{foreach from=$clients item=client}
    <tr class="{cycle values="erow,"} elements">
        <td class="tdcenter no-label">{$client->id}</td>
        <td>{$client->name}</td>
        <td>{$client->email}</td>
        <td>{$client->phone}</td>
        <td>{php} echo get_client_profit($client->name);{/php}</td>
    </tr>
 {/foreach}
```

I need to pass smarty variable `{$client->name}` to php function `get_client_profit`.  How should I do that? Is it possible?

Comment: Is adding `get_client_profit` as a `Smarty template plugin` an option? http://www.smarty.net/best_practices (#1)

Comment: @Lina what happens if you just do `{get_client_profit($client->name)}` ?

Comment: @shawndreck  it simply don't pass anything, if I write {get_client_profit('test')} it's working. :)

Comment: just wondering, is the $client an array or an object? If array then you should use $client.name. If it is an object, then perhaps try to assign the $client->name to a variable before passing it to the function

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
{foreach from=$clients item=client}
    <tr class="{cycle values="erow,"} elements">
        <td class="tdcenter no-label">{$client->id}</td>
        <td>{$client->name}</td>
        <td>{$client->email}</td>
        <td>{$client->phone}</td>
        <td>
{assign var="clientname" value=$client->name }
{php} echo get_client_profit($smarty->get_template_vars('clientname'));{/php}</td>
        </tr>
     {/foreach}
```

Comment: It's returning syntax error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')'

Answer (score 0):

I did this on my development  machine and it works:

```
{foreach from=$clients item=client}
<tr class="{cycle values="erow,"} elements">
    <td class="tdcenter no-label">{$client->id}</td>
    <td>{$client->name}</td>
    <td>{$client->email}</td>
    <td>{$client->phone}</td>
    <td>{get_client_profit($client->name)}</td>
 </tr>
 {/foreach}
```

Simply call the function without the `{php}` tags